# Density Matrices in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices

I have a question about the physical meanings of various matrices expressed in Dirac bra-kets.

I take it that $\frac{1}{2}|A\rangle\langle A| + \frac{1}{2}|B\rangle\langle B|$ can be interpreted as a classical probability distribution over $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$, where $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$ denote some eigenstates of an observable. (i.e., The system is in $|A\rangle$ with probability 1/2, in $|B\rangle$ with probability 1/2.)

Can the following matrices be associated with some similar physical interpretations?

**(M1)** $\frac{1}{2}|A\rangle\langle B| + \frac{1}{2}|B\rangle\langle A|$

**(M2)** $\frac{1}{2}|A\rangle\langle A| - \frac{1}{2}|B\rangle\langle B|$

**(M3)** $\frac{1}{2}|A\rangle\langle B| - \frac{1}{2}|B\rangle\langle A|$

Comment: As mentioned in the answer these aren't proper density matrices, but regarding the interpretation: in general the diagonal elements of a density matrix can be interpreted as occupation probability and the off diagonals corerspond to transition amplitudes.

Answer (score 1):

One of the requirements of a density matrix $\rho$ is that $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho) = 1$, so - assuming as per the context of your question that $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$ are orthonormal - M1-3 do not constitute density matrices.